# Lambda connect to redis inside ec2 within same VPC but failed with connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: aws-lambda, redis, serverless-framework

I'm using redis npm and below's a portion of my code:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient({ port: settings.redis_port, host: settings.redis_host  });
```

where when I'm developing locally in my pc, `redis_host` is set to `"127.0.0.1"` and when in lambda, `redis_host` is set to `"172.12.34.56"`. When developing locally, I need to run `ssh -i "D:/Project/mykey.pem" -fNg -L 6379:localhost:6379 ubuntu@3.1.3.90 -p 22` first before my code above can connect to redis. Anyway my local deployment connect with redis perfectly well after doing all the above.

The problem is when I deploy my code to lambda. It will always return the error

```
ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Redis connection to 172.12.34.56:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 172.12.34.56:6379","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"172.12.34.56","port":6379,"stack":["Error: Redis connection to 172.12.34.56:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 172.12.34.56:6379","    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)"]}
```

The things is, the redis resides in the same ec2 instance with my MongoDB, and my lambda can access the MongoDB without any problem using the connection string `mongoose.connect('mongodb://172.12.34.56:27017/mydb')`

I also have added the port `6379` in my ec2 instance's security group inbound rules, as in the image below:
[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

1. edit `redis.conf` and comment out `bind 127.0.0.1 ::1` and
2. set `protected-mode no`

My ec2 instance is already publicly not accessible, so turning of protected mode should not be a problem.